# Spider yields same comment multiple times when scraping comments on steam website

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a spider using scrapy to scrape comments on video game mods, and the spider then follows a link to the user's profile that left a comment and takes some additional data from their profile. When I run the spider, it is returning the same item multiple times, except the user's information does not match the comment they left, and the spider returns the same user's information multiple times.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class Workshop_Item(Item):
    game = Field()
    mod = Field()
    user = Field()
    comment = Field()
    #user_level = Field()
    date_posted = Field()


class Workshop_Comment_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "comments"
    with open("output/workshop_comment_links.txt") as f:
        urls = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]
    start_urls = urls

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Workshop_Item()
        for comment in response.css(".commentthread_comment"):


            #yield {
            #"user": comment.css("bdi::text").get(),
            #"comment": ",".join(comment.css(".commentthread_comment_text::text").getall()).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', ' '),
            #"date posted": comment.css(".commentthread_comment_timestamp::attr(title)").get()
            #}

            item['game'] = response.css(".apphub_AppName::text").get()
            item['mod'] = response.css(".workshopItemTitle::text").get()
            item['user'] = comment.css("bdi::text").get()
            item['comment'] = ",".join(comment.css(".commentthread_comment_text::text").getall()).replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', ' ')
            item['date_posted'] = comment.css(".commentthread_comment_timestamp::attr(title)").get()
            user_profile = comment.css(".commentthread_author_link::attr(href)").get()
            #print(item)
            if user_profile is not None:
                yield response.follow(user_profile, callback=self.parse_user_info, meta={'item': item})

    def parse_user_info(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        yield {
            'user_level' : response.css(".friendPlayerLevelNum::text").get(),
            'game' : item['game'],
            'mod' : item['mod'],
            'user' : item['user'],
            'comment' : item['comment'],
            'date_posted' : item['date_posted'],
        }
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: well CSS is just the stylesheet, not the actual content.  You're gonna get stuff like how big of a fontsize, and what color the background is.  It might be `response.something`, but I have doubts it'd be `response.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "item = Workshop_Item()" inside the for loop.